# How do I rebuild a custom Lucene index on a Sitecore content delivery server?

Tags: sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

The custom Lucene index on my Sitecore 6.2 Content Delivery server seems to be not right.  So I think I need to rebuild all 3 of my custom indexes.  How do I do that?  Do I just have to use the shared source Index Viewer module?  Right now I have that installed on my CD server, however for some reason it is not working.  When I select my custom index in Index Viewer - nothing happens.  So I can't rebuild the index that way.  Can I just delete the index files from the hard drive?  If so, how quickly will Lucene rebuild them?

Comment: Currently the Index Viewer does not have the ability to rebuild indexes remotely (ie from CM on CD). However I am working on a version where it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up contacting Sitecore support and they pointed me to the shared source module called Sitecore Support Toolbox - http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Support_Toolbox.aspx.  Once I installed that I was able to easily rebuild my indexes.

Comment: Anyone know where the Sitecore Support Toolbox went? It's no longer available on Marketplace.

Answer (score 3):

As noted above, earlier versions of Sitecore 6.x required custom indexes to be rebuild using either IndexViewer or with some custom code. I believe in a revision of 6.5 the Control Panel > Database > Rebuild Search Indexes began including custom indexes so IndexViewer is no longer necessary (but should still work).

To your specific question though, on my CD servers I have a rebuild script that can be called directly to rebuild search indexes. I forget where I found this script (believe it was something published by Alex Shyba at Sitecore). You can find the details of this script at https://gist.github.com/Refactored/6776801

However, I believe you have a different issue that needs to be addressed. If your CD servers aren't detecting changes and therefore not updating you have a configuration issue. I would start with this article when troubleshooting index issues: http://sitecoreblog.alexshyba.com/2011/04/search-index-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 2):

Since **Sitecore 6.6** update 3 or 4 (don't remember which one was it) you can rebuild your custom indexes from the **Sitecore Control Panel**.

In all previous versions you need to rebuild it from code or using custom modules for **Sitecore**. Deleting index files won't work.

The simplest code for rebuilding custom **Sitecore Lucene Index** is:

```
Sitecore.Search.SearchManager.GetIndex("your_index_name").Rebuild()
```

The blog post ["Troubleshooting Sitecore Lucene search and indexing"](http://www.cognifide.com/blogs/sitecore/troubleshooting-sitecore-lucene-search-and-indexing/) can help you if rebuilding the index won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have come across the same requirement in one of my projects. Here was my solution:

1. Create a configuration content item with a template that has only one field, say "**Rebuild Index**", default value is "1", example of the item path could be: "**/sitecore/content/mysite/config/index rebuild flag**"
2. Create an IndexRebuilder class that has a Run method. Within the Run method, check the "**index rebuild flag**" item (from the Context database) and rebuild the index on the server if the "**Rebuild Index**" field value equals to "1". After rebuilt successfully, update the item field value to "0".
3. Set up, a scheduled agent that points to the IndexRebuilder class. For examples,

   <agent type="MyAssembly.IndexRebuilder, MyAssembly" method="Run" interval="00:00:00"/>

   Notice that the interval is "00:00:00" by default, to turn off the agent on content management server. Your build and deployment process should turn this value to say "00:05:00", which allow the agent to run on every 5 minutes.

From there, to rebuild index on content delivery server, just publish the "**index rebuild flag**" item from master database to the content delivery database (web) and the index on your content delivery server should start rebuilding in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking Index Viewer with nothing happening, is usually an indication of certain files of the Index Viewer package having not been deployed to your CD server. Easiest fix for this - if you do have /sitecore running on the CD server - is to just re-install the package directly on the CD server. After this, IndexViewer will work.

If you don't have a /sitecore on your CD server (Sitecore recommends removing this, or at least blocking access to it) - it becomes more problematic. I would recommend setting a page/webservice or similar, executing the code Maras suggests above - that way you can always trigger an index rebuild when you need it.

Comment: There is a rebuild index script in the support toolbox. This could be selectively deployed: http://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Support_Toolbox.aspx

Comment: Nice. Hadn't seen that one before :-)